# Which species is this flower seedling?

Tags: identification, flowers, vines

Who can help me with identifying the plants shown in the picture below (on the left).

I grew them from large brown seed contained in a "Flower Seed Mix"

<sub>*Click photo for full size*</sub>
[image]

Comment: Does your package give a list of what flowers are in it? If yes, it's easier by simple elimination to identify your plants ;-) Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5):

Judging by

- the seed description,
- the tendency to climb and
- the small tendrills at the top and
- the flattish stem

together with fact that it's often in "seed mixes", this is most likely a [Sweet Pea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_pea).

Plant it near a fence or other structure where it can get a grip with the tendrils to climb or provide some other kind of support.